# ValueError on standardize_input_data()

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to implement a simple Unet network using Keras on Tensorflow 2.0 backend.

I use custom image generator without augumentated data. My templates anf masks are 1536x1536 RGB images (masks are black and white).

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
import random
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, BatchNormalization, Activation, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Lambda, RepeatVector, Reshape
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPool2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.merge import concatenate, add
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

def data_gen(templates_folder, masks_folder, image_width, batch_size): # Custom image generator
    counter = 0
    images_list = os.listdir(templates_folder)
    random.shuffle(images_list) 
    while True:
        templates_pack = np.zeros((batch_size, image_width, image_width, 3)).astype('float') 
        masks_pack = np.zeros((batch_size, image_width, image_width, 1)).astype('float')
        for i in range(counter, counter + batch_size): 
            template = cv2.imread(templates_folder + '/' + images_list[i]) / 255.
            templates_pack[i - counter] = template  

            mask = cv2.imread(masks_folder + '/' + images_list[i], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255.
            mask = mask.reshape(image_width, image_width, 1) # Add extra dimension for parity with template size [1536 * 1536 * 3]
            masks_pack[i - counter] = mask 

        counter += batch_size
        if counter + batch_size >= len(images_list): 
            counter = 0
            random.shuffle(images_list) 
        yield templates_pack, masks_pack


def conv2d_block(input_tensor, n_filters, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=True):
    x = Conv2D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size), kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(input_tensor)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size), kernel_initializer="he_normal", padding="same")(x)
    if batchnorm:
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x


def get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.5, batchnorm=True):
    c1 = conv2d_block(input_img, n_filters=n_filters * 1, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
    p1 = Dropout(dropout * 0.5)(p1)

    c2 = conv2d_block(p1, n_filters=n_filters * 2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
    p2 = Dropout(dropout)(p2)

    c3 = conv2d_block(p2, n_filters=n_filters * 4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
    p3 = Dropout(dropout)(p3)

    c4 = conv2d_block(p3, n_filters=n_filters * 8, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
    p4 = Dropout(dropout)(p4)

    c5 = conv2d_block(p4, n_filters=n_filters * 16, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    u6 = Dropout(dropout)(u6)
    c6 = conv2d_block(u6, n_filters=n_filters * 8, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    u7 = Dropout(dropout)(u7)
    c7 = conv2d_block(u7, n_filters=n_filters * 4, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    u8 = Dropout(dropout)(u8)
    c8 = conv2d_block(u8, n_filters=n_filters * 2, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(n_filters * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    u9 = Dropout(dropout)(u9)
    c9 = conv2d_block(u9, n_filters=n_filters * 1, kernel_size=3, batchnorm=batchnorm)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(c9)
    model = Model(inputs=[input_img], outputs=[outputs])
    return model

callbacks = [
EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1),
ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=3, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1),
ModelCheckpoint("model-prototype.h5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, 
save_weights_only=True)
]
train_templates_path = "E:/train/templates"
train_masks_path = "E:/train/masks"
valid_templates_path = "E:/valid/templates"
valid_masks_path = "E:/valid/masks"
TRAIN_SET_SIZE = len(os.listdir(train_templates_path))
VALID_SET_SIZE = len(os.listdir(valid_templates_path))
BATCH_SIZE = 1
EPOCHS = 100
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = TRAIN_SET_SIZE / BATCH_SIZE 
VALIDATION_STEPS = VALID_SET_SIZE / BATCH_SIZE
IMAGE_WIDTH = 1536

train_generator = data_gen(train_templates_path, train_masks_path, IMAGE_WIDTH, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
val_generator = data_gen(valid_templates_path, valid_masks_path, IMAGE_WIDTH, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)

model = get_unet(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=0.05, batchnorm=True) 
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

results = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_data=val_generator, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, callbacks=callbacks)
```

For some reason I get a following error:

```
Epoch 1/100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Explorium/python/unet_trainer.py", line 83, in <module>
    results = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, validation_data=val_generator, validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS, callbacks=callbacks)
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1297, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 265, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 973, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight, reset_metrics=reset_metrics)
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 253, in train_on_batch
    extract_tensors_from_dataset=True)
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2472, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\E-soft\Anaconda3\envs\Explorium\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 574, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected img to have shape (1536, 1536, 1) but got array with shape (1536, 1536, 3)
```

It seems that Keras can't normalize data using `standardize_input_data()`, but I have no idea why it's happening.

Comment: can you give us the model implementation too ?

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz, I've added model implementation and all imports - everything I have in a script file.

Comment: And what is `input_img`? More specifically, what is its shape?

Comment: @Orphee Faucoz as stated in the third sentence, my templates anf masks are 1536x1536 RGB images (masks are black and white). `template` is (1536, 1536, 3) and `mask` is (1536, 1536, 1) after reshaping. Template sample: https://ibb.co/4K1YjJg Mask sample: https://ibb.co/QrY436L

Comment: Yeah I saw that, what I was saying is that I think that your first layer of your model expects a  input tensor that you defined as `ìnput_img` yet I don't see it in the code and the error may come from that.

Comment: You were right! My input was defined as follows:  
`input_img = Input((IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1), name='img')`. It should be `input_img = Input((IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3), name='img')`. Thanks!